# If i insert single pointer into double pointer, zsh: segmentation fault appears

Tags: c, pointers

i was trying to split data and insert each pointer into double pointer(ptr) as below. 
In https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler, this code works well. but in Linux vi editor, `zsh: segmentation fault ./test` appears. Why this thing happens? and how should i edit??

I would really appreciate if you could answer

```c
// test.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 1024

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    char** ptr;
    char data[MAX] = "    find    a    /tmp   ";
    
    char *tmp_ptr = strtok(data," ");
    
    while(tmp_ptr!=NULL){
        printf("%s\n",tmp_ptr);
        ptr[i++] = tmp_ptr;
        tmp_ptr = strtok(NULL," ");    
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the `ptr` pointer wasn't allocated `char** ptr;`

```
char** ptr = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*));
```

realloc when you prepare to add one more element to ptr

```
ptr = (char**)realloc(ptr, i+1);
```

and `free(ptr)` when you don't use it anymore

tested at : https://godbolt.org/z/95M51Mrfs